# Express Node.js client-sessions throwing error of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I am trying to set a cookie session using `client-sessions`. I think everything should work. but it is giving me the error `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of undefined]`. I am failing to see what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
var session = require('client-sessions');

app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'secret',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  ephemeral: true
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.session && req.session.user){
    req.user = req.session;
    req.session.user = req.session;
    res.locals.user = req.session;
    next();
  }else{
    next();
  }
});
```

In my index.js

```
router.get('/leaderboardsAdmin', requireLogin, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('LeaderboardsAdmin', { isAdmin: req.session.isAdmin });
});

router.post('/AdminRequest', function(req, res){
  var pass = req.body.pass
  if(pass == "password"){
    var newSesh = {
      name: 'Admin',
      isAdmin: true
    }
    req.session = newSesh;
    res.send("1");
  }else{
    res.send("0");
  }
});

function requireLogin(req, res, next){
  if(!req.session.isAdmin){
    res.redirect('/Leaderboards');
  }else{
    next();
  }
};
```

Comment: You are setting `newSesh` on req ?

Comment: Yeah, i'm setting the session to `newSesh`.